# Css blocks missing after bundling - ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

After publishing website, I detected missing css codes, when I check the final file `site.min.css` is created but it is missing some blocks.

I have css classes like:

```
.class1, .class2 {...}
.class1 > div, .class2 > div{...}
```

However, in the bundled css it is like:

```
.class1{...}.class1>div{...}
```

I thought maybe it has a problem with comma separation but the funny thing is its working for some of them and some other classes like `.otherclass1,.otherclass2{...}` are in the bundled file.

I also validated the css file, and it is valid.

I thought maybe old files are cached and new changed are not applied, so I changed the file name of input css file, but output still missing some blocks.

This is the first time I have a problem like this. I have done this hundreds of times and never had an issue.

**Update:** I just minified the files with an online tool and it works.

Comment: In your example, you have empty CSS rules, i.e. just `{ }`. That might explain why they are removed. In reality, I'm sure you have some rules in there. Can we see a real example of disappearing blocks?

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk they are not empty, as i was giving example, I didn't just write inside`{}`